# Converting JSON Data from S3 upload, and using Lambda function to push to DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I've been working on an assignment recently and I feel like I'm very close to solving the problem I'm having, but I just can't seem to find anything that would help online.
As the title states, I've got some JSON data being uploaded from a webpage into an S3 bucket. When a new S3 item is created, I want to take that data and store it in a DynamoDB table.

I'm using a Lambda function and testing with some data I've already stored in my S3 bucket. I've got the data in its key-value pairs in my console.logs but I just can't work out why it isn't actually storing the data.

[image: Example of key-value pairs in my Lambda function test log]

On the left I have the data broken down into its key-value pair, i.e. "artist": "Elvis Presley", using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).

What I'm wondering, is how to push this data into the table.

```
var params = {
              Item: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)),
              ReturnConsumedCapacity: "TOTAL",
              TableName: "s3-to-dynamo-s00187306"
             };
             dynamo.putItem(params, dynamoResultCallback);
```

The above code is what I've been trying to use but it's giving me a timeout error. If I bump up the allowed time then I receive a different error relating to a missing partition key in the item, even though my partition key matches with one of the key values in every item.

Really stumped here, any advice is appreciated, thanks in advance.

[edit]

So I used what someone suggested below, the dynamo-db converter, and have some logs which provide some insight into what's going on.

[image]

I've now got the data in the correct format for dynamo-db, and each item is parsed correctly as far as I can tell.

As for what `dynamo` represents, I'm not 100% so I'm going to add a screenshot of its declaration at the top of my code. I think it's the doc client?

[edit 2]

So my "_class" values are all the exact same, might try changing the partition key to title instead? (nevermind this didn't work)

[image]

Comment: Share your data payload, and also your DynamoDb schema, are you using sort keys, and provide in a better way the errors that you are receiving

Comment: Always include exact error messages.

Comment: Also, is `dynamo` the low-level DynamoDB client or the Document Client?

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify(data)` return a json format that not match with Dynamodb format, Dynamodb are waiting a format like this:

```
Item: {
    'CUSTOMER_ID' : {N: '001'},
    'CUSTOMER_NAME' : {S: 'Richard Roe'}
}
```

As you see, the syntax is not the same, I think you need to use another library, maybe [dynamo-converters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamo-converters), or look at NodeJs Aws SDK maybe there is a method that can do this.

Comment: Note: the data is being stringified and then parsed.